# Return items of mapped array with unique styling elements

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

How to set different **X** values for every map element. **[left='X' px]**.
In short how to set a new className *[class in Vanilla Js]* property to the map generated elements.

```
    const sports = [ //objects
      {    
        id: 1,
        name: 'A',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'B',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'C'
      }
    ]

    const sportList = sports.map(sport => (//mapped results in array sportList
        <div className = "show-test" >
          <div className = "show" > {sport.name} < /div> 
          <div className = "channel-time" >
            {
              dStart.getHours() + ':' 
              + dStart.getMinutes() + ' - ' 
              + dEnd.getHours() + ':' 
              + dEnd.getMinutes()
            } 
          </div> 
        </div>
      )
    )

    return (
      <>
        <div className = "show-div" >
          <div className = "show-item-name" >
            <div className = "show-test2" > {sportList} </div> 
          </div>  
        </div>
      </>
    )
```

Comment: can you explain more about your problem?  what is your expectation?

Comment: please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement. Good luck 

Comment: @novonimo I want to style the returned mapped data.

Comment: @novonimo Sorry will keep it in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are talking about adding diffrent classes to mapped result:

```
     const sports = [{    //object
        id: 1,
        name: 'A',
        class:"class1"

      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'B',
        class:"class2"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'C'
        class:"class3"

      }
    ]
 
 

   const sportList = sports.map(sport => (     //mapped results in a new array sportsList
    <div className = {sport.class} >
      <div className = "show" > {sport.name} < /div> <div className = "channel-time" >
      {dStart.getHours() + ':' + dStart.getMinutes() + ' - ' + dEnd.getHours() + ':' + dEnd.getMinutes()} 
      </div> 
      </div>
    ))
    
    return ( <
      >
    
      <div className = "show-div" >
      <div className = "show-item-name" >
      <div className = "show-test2" > {sportList} 
      </div> 
      </div>  
      </div>
      </>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly where you are trying to add the className in this example. But if it is inside this map then you can find the index by adding `index` into the `.map` args, e.g.

```
const sportList = sports.map((sport, index) => (     //mapped results in a new array sportsList
<div className = `show-test your-class-${index}` >
  <div className = "show" > {sport.name} < /div> <div className = "channel-time" >
  {dStart.getHours() + ':' + dStart.getMinutes() + ' - ' + dEnd.getHours() + ':' + dEnd.getMinutes()} 
  </div> 
  </div>
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the map callback function, you can generate a unique `className` from the current index in the array.

eg

```
className={`show-test show-test-${i}`}
```

```
const sports = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "A"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "B"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "C"
  }
];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {sports.map((sport, i) => (
        <div className={`show-test show-test-${i}`}>
          <div className="show"> {sport.name} </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: Edit eager-cache-c4vih]

You can do the same thing with any attribute, such as `style`.

```
const sports = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "A"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "B"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "C"
  }
];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {sports.map((sport, i) => (
        <div
          className="show-test"
          style={{
            marginLeft: i * 20 + "px"
          }}
        >
          <div className="show"> {sport.name} </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: Edit hardcore-voice-h1qn0]